# Search sales orders filtered by customer using Netsuite php toolkit

Tags: php, web-services, netsuite

I need to search all sales orders for a specific customer ( using customer internal id or entity id ). When I run below script, it returns all sales orders ( 20 for a page). How to filter that result by customer?

```
require_once 'PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';

$service = new NetSuiteService();


    $service->setSearchPreferences(false, 20);

    $SearchEnumMultiSelectField = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
    $SearchEnumMultiSelectField->searchValue = Array('_salesOrder');
    $SearchEnumMultiSelectField->operator = 'anyOf';

    $search = new TransactionSearchBasic();
    $search->type = $SearchEnumMultiSelectField;

    //$search->customForm = new SearchMultiSelectField();
    //$id = new RecordRef();
    //$id->internalId = 'xxxxxx';  customer internal Id
    //$search->customForm->searchValue = $id;


    $request = new SearchRequest();
    $request->searchRecord = $search;

    $searchResponse = $service->search($request);

    echo print_r($searchResponse,true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        $service = new NetSuiteService(self::_config);
        $customerSearchBasic = new CustomerSearchBasic();

        $searchValue = new RecordRef();
        $searchValue->type = 'customer';
        $searchValue->internalId = $customer_id;

        $searchMultiSelectField = new SearchMultiSelectField();
        setFields($searchMultiSelectField, array('operator' => 'anyOf', 'searchValue' => $searchValue));
        $customerSearchBasic->internalId = $searchMultiSelectField;

        $transactionSearchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();

        $searchMultiSelectEnumField = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
        setFields($searchMultiSelectEnumField, array('operator' => 'anyOf', 'searchValue' => "_salesOrder"));

        $transactionSearchBasic->type = $searchMultiSelectEnumField;
        $transactionSearch = new TransactionSearch();
        $transactionSearch->basic = $transactionSearchBasic;
        $transactionSearch->customerJoin = $customerSearchBasic;

        $request = new SearchRequest();
        $request->searchRecord = $transactionSearch;
        $searchResponse = $service->search($request);

        if ($searchResponse->searchResult->status->isSuccess) {
            if(isset($searchResponse->searchResult->recordList)) {
                return $searchResponse->searchResult->recordList->record;
            }
        }
```